# Anchored modal footer

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an angular-ui modal window, which can contain more elements, than the screen can contain. Naturally, modal is automatically scrolling, but I need to scroll to the bottom to see the modal-footer.

Is it possible to anchor the footer, so scrolling does not affect it, resulting in footer to be always visible?

Working example here

Comment: please add fiddle or plunker it make easy to understand problem

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/88wUw3Yoqqt6Q5XLu8Lh?p=preview

as you can see here, in order to press 'OK' or 'Cancel' I need to scroll down. What I want is to anchor the footer so i can see these buttons all the time, without the need to scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the modal's body `max-height` and `overflow:scroll` properties to achieve the effect you are after.

http://plnkr.co/edit/u1gdVHiv1bNOpfZ203rt?p=preview

```
<div class="modal-header">
    ...
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="max-height:400px; overflow-x:scroll;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    ...
</div>
```